# How to manipulate these values to related column id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So I'm getting these values from the REST APIs. However, it doesn't have fields to them. I'm trying to assign each value in each of these arrays to a record and the corresponding column.

How I'm getting the data from the backend service:

**[["name1", null,0]], [["name2", null, 2]], [["name3", null, 1]]**

This is what I need:

**{
type: null,
Name: name1,
Count: 0
}**
,

**{
type: null,
Name: name2,
Count: 2
}**

**{
type: null,
Name: name3,
Count: 1
}**

Furthermore: Im trying assign each value to a field. I'm doing this to be able to map those fields to a table by each record corresponding to the column id.

Comment: can you change data from the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map function. I'm assuming that the data you get back is an array containing single "tuple" element where the tuple has propertis for "Name", "type", and "Count" attributes in positions 0, 1, and 2.

Below is an example taking your server data and mapping it how I think you are asking.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function MainController() {
    // Your server output
    var serverOutput = [
      [
        ["name1", null, 0]
      ],
      [
        ["name2", null, 2]
      ],
      [
        ["name3", null, 1]
      ]
    ];
    var self = this;

    self.$onInit = function $onInit() {
      self.items = serverOutput.map(function toItemType(serverArr) {
        return {
          type: serverArr[0][1],
          Name: serverArr[0][0],
          Count: serverArr[0][2]
        };
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as $ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
      <div>Type: {{::item.type}}</div>
      <div>Name: {{::item.Name}}</div>
      <div>Count: {{::item.Count}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not just 3 arrays like that, it's total of 120 arrays with 3 values in each so I can't manually code it and assign it to a variable. I subscribe that response to variable then do the mapping right? thank you for answering :)

Comment: The above should apply to any number of arrays according to the sample you gave. Can you provide more details (or more to the sample server response) where we can tweak the mapping function to do what you need. I'm assuming the backend service is producing the output with some logic -- I've not seen a response like yours before :)

Comment: This actually helped me figure it out! Thank you! I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

hope you well
here is your solution in JavaScript,

```js
     var apiData = [
          [
            ["name1", null, 0]
          ],
          [
            ["name2", null, 2]
          ],
          [
            ["name3", null, 1]
          ]
        ];
    
    
    
    var arryObj = []
    
    apiData.map((a,i)=>arryObj.push({name:a[0][0],type:a[0][1],Count:a[0][2]}))
    
    console.log(arryObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put those three arrays in one array and loop over it and create the objects:

```
let arr = [[["name1", null,0]], [["name2", null, 2]], [["name3", null, 1]]]
arr.map(i => {
  const obj = {
    type: i[0][1],
    name: i[0][0],
    count: i[0][2]
  }
  console.log(obj)
})
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/2nsrxz85/).

Answer (score 0):

here is simple way

```js
var apiData = [
          [
            ["name1", null, 0]
          ],
          [
            ["name2", null, 2]
          ],
          [
            ["name3", null, 1]
          ]
        ];
    
    
    
apiData = apiData.map((a,i)=>({name:a[0][0],type:a[0][1],Count:a[0][2]}))

console.log(apiData)
```